# Android send JSON body with emojis to a nodejs server

Tags: android, node.js, http, emoji

I'm trying to send a PATCH request to my nodejs server from android. I can send plain text inside JSON without any error. But when I add some emojis in JSON, the server throws `SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON`. I can send emojis from postman without any issue. I guess something is wrong with my android code.
Here is the code for android,

```
private JSONObject sendData(){
JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
jsonParam.put("text", "this will work fine");
jsonParam.put("payload", "This will throw error");

StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        JSONObject obj = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(baseUrl + path);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod(method);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            //os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
            os.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());
            ////
            InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while (line != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data.append(line);
            }
            obj = new JSONObject(data.toString());

            os.flush();
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("SEND_REQUEST_ERROR", e.toString());
        }
        return obj;
}
```

Comment: You can check which encoding uses Postman to send your emoji inspecting the request and use the same to encode your emoji on Android before adding it to the JSON object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private String convertStringToUTF8(String s) {
       return new String(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    }

jsonParam.put("payload", convertStringToUTF8("This will work without error"));
```